# Exponential of infinite dimensional matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential, tridiagonal-matrices

<sub>Originally posted on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4186073) but didn't get any responses. Thus, I thought I would ask here with some more details.</sub>

---

I have a matrix originating from Master Equation for birth death process on semi infinite lattice. It is tridiagonal. It is not symmetric.

I wanted to know if there is any way to compute the elements of $e^{(H−\lambda_1 I)t}$
where $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue of $H$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

The matrix I have looks like this:
\begin{pmatrix} 0&d&0&0&.&.&.\\ 0&-(b+d)&2d&0&.&.&.\\ 0&b&-(2b+2d)&3d&0&.&.\\0&0&2b&-(3b+3d)&4d&0&.\\ .&.&0&3b&-(4b+4d)&5d&.\\.&.&.\end{pmatrix}

$b$ and $d$ are birth and death rates and both are positive. This is an infinite matrix since it is over all possible lattice sites. I don't know of any approximate methods either. That would be helpful too. This is a sparse tridiagonal matrix. But I don't know if I can apply the approximate methods that exist for finite matrices.

Any help would be appreciated!

PS: From writing the generating function for the probability distribution and calculating it at long times, I know the first eigenvalue and the first eigenstate. But it is too complicated to write an expansion of the generating function for all times. Hence, I do not know how the other eigenstates look like. I also know that the zeroth eigenvalue is 0 and the corresponding eigenstate. Maybe that would help somehow?

Comment: It would be helpful to replace dots with actual values in the 4th line.

Comment: Added the relevant elements. :)

Comment: What is the value of $\lambda_1$ ?

Comment: $\lambda_1 = \frac{b-d}{d}$ is what I have

Comment: what is the generating function for an eigenvector? you have a 3-term recurrence to solve, a lot is known about them.